# Showing $a\cdot b = 0$ is associative

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ be an abelian group. Show that $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is associative if we deﬁne $a\cdot b = 0$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I did this:

\begin{align*}
ab&=0\\ 
ab\cdot c &= 0\cdot c\\ 
ab\cdot bc &= 0\cdot bc,\\ 
ab\cdot b^{-1}\cdot bc &= 0\cdot b^{-1}\cdot bc,
\end{align*}

and since $b\cdot b^{-1} = e$ and $0\cdot b^{-1} = ab\cdot b^{-1}= a$, $a\cdot bc = a\cdot bc$, hence, it is associative.

Is it true?

Comment: What are you doing with $b^{-1}$? There is no $b^{-1}$ in this structure.

Comment: You want to show that $(a.b).c=a.(b.c)$, for all $a,b,c$. I don't see you have shown that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overthinking it. You want to show that $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot(b\cdot c)$.

As $a\cdot b = 0$, $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = 0\cdot c = 0$. Now show that $a\cdot (b\cdot c) = 0$.

Comment: You don't even need to know that $a.b=0$, since $(a.b).c=0$ by definition :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Of course. Turns out I was also overthinking it.

Comment: Can you please solve this long? :/

Comment: @user157059: I'd rather you do it. Do you understand why $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = 0$?

Comment: In order to show being associative, don't we have to show that (ab)c=a(bc)? ab=0, (ab).c=0.c=0, so (ab).c=0 . I understand this, but how will I show this?

Comment: @user157059: You just did. What else do you need?

Comment: which completes the proof?

Comment: Well, you showed that $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = 0$, now you just need to show that $a\cdot(b\cdot c) = 0$. Once you've done that, you have $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = 0 = a\cdot(b\cdot c)$.

Comment: Don't we have to show the proof of right side of the equation? I mean, a.(bc)=0

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "now you just need to show that $a\cdot(b\cdot c) = 0$."